# How to make the screen not flicker?

Tags: c++, windows

I want to be able to draw all my text, lines , triangles and other stuff to screen and then clear the screen and draw something new, BUT this method makes the screen flicker, and all the drawings dont appear at the same time.

My idea is to draw to some kind of a buffer and then draw that buffer to the screen and clear the buffer, and repeat. This way the screen wont flicker and all will be drawn at the same time.

I am using windows.h , Visual Studio.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct vec2d
{
    int x, y;
};

void Line(HDC dc, vec2d a, vec2d b)
{
    MoveToEx(dc, a.x, a.y, NULL);
    LineTo(dc, b.x, b.y);
}

vec2d GetMousePos(HWND console)
{
    vec2d out;
    POINT p;
    GetCursorPos(&p);
    out.x = p.x; out.y = p.y;       
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    HWND console = GetConsoleWindow();
    HDC dc = GetDC(console);
    SelectObject(dc, CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(255, 255, 255)));

    while (1)
    {
        //BitBlt(dc, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 0, 0, BLACKNESS);        Flickering is much much bigger, because its faster
        system("cls");
        Line(dc, { 0, 0 }, GetMousePos(console));       
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance, Mark.

Comment: It sounds like you're describing the standard graphics technique called [double buffering or page flipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics). Have you searched for [existing Q&A on achieving double buffering in Windows GDI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153387/double-buffering-win32-c)?

Comment: I did seaech on google but I wasnt sure what to search for.

Comment: Yes as DMGregory pointed out it's double buffering. In time you may want to consider a graphics API like DirectX or OpenGL.

Comment: Cant i make my own ? i know it would be slow and stuff like that